# loop through a collection of range of numbers in one line powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a way to loop through a collection of range of numbers in PowerShell. I have tried below and it works

```
foreach ($i in 1..3)
{
    "$i"
}

foreach ($i in 1,2,3)
{
    "$i"
}
```

However when I try below, I get a error message

```
foreach ($i in 1..3,4..8)
{
  "$i"
}
```

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]"
> to type "System.Int32". At line:1 char:1
>
> - $collection1 = 1..3,4..8
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
>   ```

Is there a way to loop through a collection of range of numbers in PowerShell.

Comment: _add_ the two range arrays with `+`. your code tries to build an array of arrays. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that

```
foreach ($i in 1..3,4..8)
```

will pass to the foreach enumerator an array of two elements. The first element is an array that contains values 1,2,3 and the second is also an array that contains values 4-8. However, foreach expects to find values from a collection, not other collections (arrays in this case).

To get one array for foreach, create two arrays and add those together. Like so,

```
$a1 = 1..3
$a2 = 4..8
$k = $a1+$a2

foreach($i in $k) {$i}           
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Or, wrap the ranges in parenthesis so the result is converted to a single array:

```
foreach($i in (1..3),(4..8)) {$i}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```